# statusBar event to go top of viewController [iOS].

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

Is there option of that to enable/disable it when person touch the clock of statusbar the app go to the top of viewController.

I created an app the main viewController doesn't work and others it works well, I didn't know if it is an option or API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a `UIScrollView` or `UITableView`.

Then you need to implement the following method from the `UIScrollViewDelegate` or `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return YES; // Will now scroll to the top when touching the statusBar
}
```